# Firebase Functions Express : How to get URL params with paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have a url in the form www.a.com/users/uid, I want to get `uid`.

Assume a function :

`exports.smartlink = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>`

Doing `req.params` returns an empty array, whereas `req.query.uid` when the url contains query strings works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your URL is "www.a.com/users/uid", "uid" will be part of [req.path](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.path).  You can [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) that on '/' to get the uid as the last element of the array returned by split.

You can only use `req.params` with Cloud Functions for Firebase when you're exporting an entire Express app that defines a router that uses a placeholder for the element in the path you want to extract.

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively, you can use express in firebase. and use req.param to get the value.

Comment: Please give a code example using express